# Mongodb Aggregate date range to retrieve last record of each month

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I want to be able to set a date range and then only retrieve the last record of each month.

I have an idea of how to do it but need to run it past you guys who are much wiser than I at this stuff.

I think I would do do a $group which includes the `month` and `year` number from the 'local_date_time'. I would then `$sort` by `year`, `month` and then `local_date_time` and then in the next stage, `$project` only the `$last` record for each.

Is that the best way to do this or is there a cleaner more effective way of doing this? Thanks, Matt

Comment: Could you give example of your document and  the request?

Comment: I would suggest first do `$match` to match date in range with '$gte` and  `$lte` then `$group` then `sort`

Comment: @the_mahasagar thanks for your advice. I've tried to do that and have run into problems. I've added an additional answer to this thread to explain. Have I overcooked this one you think? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
db.users.aggregate({
$match: {
        'createdDate': {
            $gte: new Date('2015'+'-01-01T00:00:00.000+0530'), 
            $lte: new Date('2015'+'-12-31T23:59:59.000+0530') 
        }
    },
},{
$group:{
        _id : { month: { $month: '$createdDate' }},
        lastUserEmail: { $last: "$email" }
    }
});
```

`$last` : Returns a value from the last document for each group, check [This..](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)

I have just checked with `createdDate`,
You can change the fields acordingly..!

hope, this will help u in some way..!

Comment: thanks for your help with this, seems to be working well, I have other issues I''m working through with the `$match` on date range. I will tryr your way and see how it goes